# Dagger 2 on Android, missing error messages

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-databinding, annotation-processing, kapt

I'm using Dagger 2 in my Android project and I'm having trouble debugging it. I know that the compilation fails because of an error in my dagger 2 setup (had it before) but it's almost impossible to track it down because I don't get a proper error message telling me where the problem lies. All I get are messages that show that the annotation processing failed. Along the lines of:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(14, 28) error: cannot find symbol class BR
Error:(17, 40) error: package com.some.package.databinding does not exist
Error:(17, 51) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerSomeComponent
...
```

Maybe it's somehow related to the fact that I'm also using databinding!?

I'm using Dagger 2.5, Gradle plugin 2.1.2 and android-apt 1.8.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It apparently does not see the this package: `package com.some.package.databinding does not exist`, and so it cannot find the class. Does this class exist in this package and is it `public`?

Comment: Well yes, classes in this package get generated by the data binding annotation processor. But it seems like it doesn't get there because the Dagger annotation processing fails before (but somehow doesn't show a proper error).

Comment: Hm, you might want to revisit the dagger2 official 'get-started' guide and see did you miss any steps of the implementation.

Comment: Well as long as Dagger is happy, everything worka fine. It's just that when something is wrong, it doesn't tell me which makes it really hard to find out what's wrong

Comment: @beeezn I have this same exact issue, did you ever find a solution? I never get to see any annotation processor exceptions, so I have no idea what is wrong with my Dagger setup.

Comment: @AustynMahoney Sorry for the late answer. Unfortunately I did not. I managed to find the error that caused the compile error but I still do not get proper error messages from Dagger...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Java

`javac` by default will only show up to 100 errors. You are probably over this limit because of databinding reporting an error for each binding class it generates.

Add this to your apps's `build.gradle`:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500"
    }
}
```

---

### Kotlin

You can enable the same javac option when using `kapt` by adding the following to your build.gradle.

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
    }
}
```

This is currently ignored, but will be [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21264) in Kotlin `v1.2.20`.

Comment: You are a real life saver, works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer, you definitely a life saver.

Comment: Don't forget to nest the code snippet given above inside your build.gradle's allprojects { ... } block.

Comment: @MauriceGavin This doesn't have to be nested at all if it is in the app's `build.gradle`, which is where my instructions have you put it.

Comment: My dagger errors only showed themselves once I ran a build from the command line: `./gradlew assembleHoneybeeDebug`